# React router with basename also matches routes without the base path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want my app to be served from a subdirectory , say `localhost:3000/test` ,
So that the routes `tab1` and `tab2` are served at `localhost:3000/test/tab1` and `localhost:3000/test/tab2`

I tried using `basename` in React `Router` for this.

It works.

However, just `localhost:3000/tab1` also matches the `tab1` component and same for `tab2`.

How do I prevent this from happening?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router basename="/test">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/tab1" render={props => <div>Hello</div>} />
        <Route path="/tab2" render={props => <div>Hi</div>} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Tip: Always [post the relevant code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the question itself.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal , done,thanks

Comment: Have you tried<Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/test/tab1" render={props => <div>Hello</div>} />
        <Route path="/test/tab2" render={props => <div>Hi</div>} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>

Comment: Hi @HemadriDasari,that is not an option unfortunately,the basename is actually derived from an environment variable, so can't hard-code the paths inside the `Route` handlers

Comment: Hi @Cyka, did you ever resolve this problem? I'm looking for an answer myself.

Comment: Hey @Marisha, as far as I can recall, I think I used the homepage attribute in package.json in this case

Answer (score -1):

The router basename is composed for react-router's Link component but not for Route.

```
<Link to="/tab1"/> 
// <a href="/test/tab1">
```

Answer (score -1):

As long as the react-router does not support this feature, you need to use something like

`<a href="/"></a>`

More details are described in this issue https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6777